# Combing text output with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm having an issue with parsing a link from a file because it's not a full link, text to be parsed is:

```
<enclosure url="/itunes/463/RKBU-How-the-Seas-Shaped-Humanit-02019_09_24_13_40_18-0.mp3" length="83586948" type="audio/mpeg"/>
```

The link should be:

```
https://www.opednews.com/itunes/463/RKBU-How-the-Seas-Shaped-Humanit-02019_09_24_13_40_18-0.mp3
```

How would I include the first part of the website address into the the link produced in the following output so the address is a full one? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
def get_playable_podcast1(soup1):
    subjects = []
    for content in soup1.find_all('item', limit=9):
        try:
            link = content.find('enclosure')
            link = link.get('url')
            print("\n\nLink: ", link)
            title = content.find('title')
            title = title.get_text()
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        item = {
                'url': link,
                'title': title,
                'thumbnail': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/21/OpEdNews_%28logo%29.jpg/200px-OpEdNews_%28logo%29.jpg",
        }
        subjects.append(item)
    return subjects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` with `urllib.parse.urljoin`:

```
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url, html = 'https://www.opednews.com', '<enclosure url="/itunes/463/RKBU-How-the-Seas-Shaped-Humanit-02019_09_24_13_40_18-0.mp3" length="83586948" type="audio/mpeg"/>'
result = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, soup(html, 'html.parser').enclosure['url'])
```

Output:

```
'https://www.opednews.com/itunes/463/RKBU-How-the-Seas-Shaped-Humanit-02019_09_24_13_40_18-0.mp3'
```